# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1). Trying to upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

When I try to install any anything, I am facing the below error.

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic (4.13.5-041305.201710050600) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.13.5-041305-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.5-041305-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.5-041305-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.5-041305-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.5-041305-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.5-041305-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.5-041305-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.5-041305-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.5-041305-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.13.5-041305-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I rebooted many times but no luck. I have installed shadowsocksR and openvpn. Don't know I am facing this problem for this two installation. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please copy those text and add to your post text images or image texts not allowed!

Comment: What Ubuntu are you running?  It looks like kernel 4.13 (17.10) which is EOL for an error I can't read on your picture (looks like dangling link?).  Please use text.  I'd also include the command as why would you setup/install an EOL kernel? or are you trying to `do-release-upgrade` from the EOL release?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I added text from command line.

Comment: your output said `Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic`. you still have kernel incomplete config, try update ,upgrade and `apt --configure -a` sir

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri getting this error::
 Command line option --configure is not understood in combination with the other options

Comment: use `dpkg --configure -a` sir

Comment: Make that `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Still getting that error. 

Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.13.5-041305-generic

Comment: try to reinstall `apt-get install linux-image*` sir

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri no luck brother :-(

Comment: try to use `dpkg reconfigure -a`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and did some more debugging. On my machine, this is the last part of content of `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc`:

```
# We use date, hwclock and dumpe2fs
copy_exec /bin/date /bin
copy_exec /sbin/hwclock /sbin
copy_exec /sbin/dumpe2fs /sbin
```

It seems that the task of this hook is to add those three tools to the initramfs. When you run `update-initramfs -u -k all -v`, it gives you verbose output what it does and when it fails. For me, it processed `date` and `hwclock` and then failed. So obviously, it was unable to add `dumpe2fs`.

To fix this, I installed `dumpe2fs` with the following command: `sudo apt install e2fsprogs`. Afterwards, it worked fine.